# Does this samsung SSD is compatible with my laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Hey I just want to know that does this [samsung 870 evo](https://dl.flipkart.com/dl/samsung-870-evo-500-gb-laptop-desktop-internal-solid-state-drive-mz-77e500bw/p/itme29010ec39f84?pid=IHDGY4JHGMKR4DHW&cmpid=product.share.pp) is compatible with my Lenovo IdeaPad 520 laptop or not?? I planning to replace my laptop HDD with 500GB ssd... I had conversation with a customer care and he told me that your laptop will support sata 3 ssd... But when I asked him that does this samsung 870 evo will support or not then he told me that sry I can't recommend you any third party ssd..  so guys help me out to know that does this ssd will support my laptop or not??

Comment: You can replace any SATA HDD with any SATA SSD - if the SATA SSD is not larger (in physical dimensions) as the HDD. Check this out before buying the SSD. Some very compact devices may use HDDs smaller than 2.5" or with reduced height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should work fine in the HDD slot.  I note this laptop also takes 2.5" M.2 PCIE SSD's - these will be more performant (but if you are already using that slot, replacing the current HDD or empty HDD slot with an SSD is a good idea)

Comment: Noop I don't think so that I am using M.2 SSD slot... I don't even know that it exists in my laptop